# mysql Stored procedures can be seen but cannot be executed by authorised user

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mariadb, privileges

I have created a small DB (MariaDB, in a XAMPP environment) for my group, and we are currently using phpmyadmin to interact with the DB. I have created users and given them different permissions depending on their specific usage needs; and this works fine for tables and views. However something seems wrong with stored procedures. I need to give the user Global SELECT and EXECUTE privileges in order for them to run them. If I do it at the database level procedures can be seen but cannot be executed.

I normally create the procedures from mysql workbench, and the look like this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `proc_name`()
BEGIN
...
END
```

And users are like:`user1@%` although I have also tried creating user like `user1@localhost` but it doesn't help.

Any idea why this is happening? Does it have to do with the DEFINER?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You need the execute privilege to execute a stored proc, so that behavior is expected. What do you mean by global select?

Comment: Try with `user1@%` and connect with that user it will work. Or adding `sql security invoker` will make them to execute by what privilege they have. Make sure `execute` is given as mentioned by Shadow

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! To answer to Shadow, If I give them the execute privilege on the procedure itself or on the entire database, they cannot execute it.. only if I grant them with global execute and select privileges at the server level. But of course I do not want them to see or execute all databases, tables or procedures that are in the server..

Comment: Since execute is the only privilege required to execute a stored proc, the only reason for additional privileges is if the definer / invoker user does not have the necessary access rights to the underlying data. To me it is not clear if you use definer or invoker context.

Comment: I am using DEFINER root@localhost, so in theory any other user should be able to execute the proc. with those privileges...is that correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct - the stored proc will run under the root account. The user invoking it must have the execute privilege.